# How to execute a PowerShell file from stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, powershell, stored-procedures

How do I execute a PowerShell file from inside a stored procedure?

I have not had any luck executing the PowerShell file from within a stored procedure.

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'powershell ""E:\PowershellScripts\todayErrorLog.ps1""'
```

When I run the stored procedure, I get access is denied errors on the file. I know the ps1 file itself is good because I can execute it both on the command line and as an Agent job. So I figure it's a matter of giving the stored procedure sufficient permissions.

[image: Access denied errors]

Previously, I made sure to enable `xp_cmdshell` with this script

```
-- To allow advanced options to be changed.  
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
GO  

-- To update the currently configured value for advanced options.  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO  

-- To enable the feature.  
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1;  
GO  

-- To update the currently configured value for this feature.  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO
```

What else do I need to do in order to execute the PowerShell script file from the stored procedure?

This is the stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[RefreshErrorQuery] 
    -- No parameters    
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    -- Step 1
    exec xp_cmdshell 'powershell ""E:\PowershellScripts\todayErrorLog.ps1""'

    -- Step 2: TODO: Run SSIS package
END
```

Comment: Have you considered just executing that SQLAgent job you mentioned from within the stored procedure?  I've never tried running powershell direct from a proc, but I have executed agent jobs from within a proc and there are ample examples both here an in on-line help to do that.

Comment: It's all because of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38624228/trigger-stored-procedure-from-view-and-refresh-view-after-stored-procedure-compl. A suggestion was that I convert my Agent Job into a stored procedure so my MVC controller could know when the process was finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is because the account that the agent is using does not have sufficient permissions to access the file.

How to check:

(1)  You can run PS from the command line
(2)  You cannot run the script from within xp_cmdshell
(3)  Change the folder containing the file to full control by Everyone
(4)  Try running the script via xp_cmdshell

Alternatively for a test, you can change the login SQL Agent is running under to your credentials.  Then the agent is running as "you", the same as if you are running on the command line.

Comment: Agent has no problem running it. Its when I try to execute the file in a stored procedure that I have the problem.

Comment: Is agent able to run it as a scheduled job (as opposed to running it interactively via SMS)?  Running the job interactively via SMS uses your login credentials as opposed to the agent credentials.

Comment: I can run it as a scheduled job -- the underlying issue is that I would like to be able to use a MVC controller method to trigger an Agent Job to run on demand and refresh the view once the job is done. I have been told that I need to run a stored procedure instead of a job, and the stored procedure runs the job asynchronously and won't inform me when it's complete.