# SQL Stored Procedure accessing Excel for calculation and retrieval of result

Tags: sql-server, excel

I need to setup within my DB logic (SP) a mechanism what will:

1. Access an external Excel,
2. Set values within pre-defined cells,
3. Have the Excel performing a specific calculation (formulae are part of the Excel itself),
4. Retrieve the result of the calculation from a pre-defined cell.

> Before someone asks why not doing the calculations within the DB: The Excel is a purchased product that underwent international certification (some chemistry coefficients stuff), and reproducing the same calculation within the DB requires undergoing the same certification process.

Now, I saw in [here](https://www.toadworld.com/platforms/sql-server/w/wiki/10425.access-excel-sheets-as-a-table-in-sql-server) some descriptions about how to retrieve data from Excel worksheets, but (so it appears) it is not easy to get the Excel to perform the calculation.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I haven't done it myself, but there's a few pointers here: https://superuser.com/questions/232656/how-do-you-update-an-excel-file-data-refresh-and-update-formulas-without-openi

Comment: Can you not use a CLR function?

Comment: Thank you @SchmitzIT for your reply. Are you suggesting that, from the DB, I go to **shell** to execute some other program that would access Excel? If yes, I would like to think that there is a simple way.

Comment: Thank you @JonathanWillcock for your comment. Please see my response to SchmitzIT above.

Comment: No I am suggesting you write a CLR routine, say in C#, which is then included as an assembly within SQL Server.  Within the c# routine, you should be able to open and play with excel and return values.  I haven't tried manipulating Excel within a CLR, and there may be some restrictions, but I've done it plenty of times using c# from outside SQL Server!

Comment: Well @JonathanWillcock, accessing Excel from a program (C# or any other language) is quite common (I had the chance to do in the past). My question is focused on doing it **_from within a SQL Server Stored Procedure_**.

Comment: @FDavidov Stored procedures typically are intended to do work within the database itself. If you want to use external (i.e. non-SQL Server) functionality, you might have to enable usage of xp_cmdshell (which allows you to run stuff within a command shell), or do as suggested using CLR code. I don't think it's possible using a stock procedure (but I might be wrong in that).

Comment: @SchmitzIT, please check the [link](https://www.toadworld.com/platforms/sql-server/w/wiki/10425.access-excel-sheets-as-a-table-in-sql-server) I mentioned in my question. From there you can see that **READING** data is possible and supported.

Comment: That is what I am saying.  If you build a CLR function, you can call it like any other SQL function!  I.e. from within SQL Server

Comment: Take a peek at https://raresql.com/2013/02/25/sql-server-excel-financial-functions-using-clr/

Comment: @FDavidov - The reading part is not the issue. It's getting Excel to update the workbook that poses the problem, though ;)

Comment: @SchmitzIT EXACTLY!!

Comment: Having had a spare 30 mins to experiment, I regret having to say that you cannot in fact access Excel through CLR.  The reason for this is that Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel requires an additional reference to Microsoft.CSharp and Microsoft.CSharp is not supported in SQL Server.  My apologies.

Comment: How about updating the excelworkbook with a powershell script [link](http://sqlmag.com/powershell/update-excel-spreadsheets-powershell) and calling that script from the stored procedure [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38642066/how-to-execute-a-powershell-file-from-stored-procedure)?

Comment: @MarcoVos, the problem is that it is not trivial to get a result from a shell script.

Comment: @FDavidov - You would be  using the shell script just for updating  the excelsheet (i.e. performing the calculation). Not for getting a result back.

Comment: @MarcoVos, READING (SELECT) an external Excel or WRITING (INSERT/UPDATE) into it can be done directly from within a stored procedure (see the link in the body of the question). The issue is that when you write, it (apparently) does not trigger the "CALCULATE" within the Excel.

Comment: @FDavidov - I understand. My suggestion is to  trigger the "CALCULATE" (step 3) by calling a powershell script from the same stored procedure (after the writing (insert/update))(step 1, 2). The powershell script updates (recalculates) the workbook. After that you can read the calculated values from the same stored procedure (step 4).

Comment: @MarcoVos not a good solution: (1) Many users may be accessing the same file at the same time, meaning that you MUST open the file in read-only mode (and hence the changes that you do in the first step will not be saved). (2) If you decide to open-write the file, you can end up having USER-A getting the result of USER-B and vise-versa.

Comment: So you're also saying many people may do this at the same time? you could try using the `xp_OA` SP's which let you access COM which should let you do the things you need. But it's likely it'll be unstable and is definitely unsupported. https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/automating-excel-from-sql-server. Is it _still_ certified when you use a process like this to access it?

Comment: A far more robust method would be to build a queuing mechanism external to SQL Server that services a queue of requests in a table. Your stored proc writes to the queue table and waits. An external process pulls waiting orders out of the queue, pushes them through Excel (with all the error handling and memory management required to make this reliable) then drops the answer back in the table and marks it as services. Your SP notes it's complete and returns the value.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, in my humble opinion, putting a DB process into a WAIT state is part of the "**NEVER EVER DARE TO DO THAT**" list. Still, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Well it's easy enough to make it asynchronous by various means. The proc doesn't have to wait. That's the good thing about a queue being the middle man.  Whatever you do it's far more robust than having a hard integration with an Excel sheet. This would be unreliable and affect system stability.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, about robustness and stability, I would say that it very much depends on how you implement and **couple** things. One more thing (I missed in one of your previous posts): multi-users, yes, but the changes of accessing the same mechanism in parallel, though it is non-zero, it is extremely small. Also, the file would be open in READ-ONLY mode and never saved, so I can't really think of any real risk.